# Relative distance between two floating-point numbers

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point

Let $\mathbb G(q,l)$ to be the set of all floating-point numbers in the base $q$ and with a mantissa of a length $l$. In the lecture notes I am trying to learn from, the following is said to be *obvious* (and consequently has no proof):

$$ \forall x \in \mathbb G(q,l), \forall y \in \mathbb G(q,l)\setminus\{x\}: |x-y| \ge |x|q^{-l} $$

What I have tried so far:

Let $x=(-1)^m a \cdot q^\alpha$ and $y=(-1)^n b \cdot q^\beta \in \mathbb G(q,l)$ such that $x \ne y$, then

\begin{align} |x-y| &\ge |x|-|y| 
 \\ &=|(-1)^m a \cdot q^\alpha|-|(-1)^n b \cdot q^\beta|
 \\ &=a \cdot q^\alpha - b \cdot q^\beta
 \\ &\ge ...?
\end{align}

Comment: It's certainly not true if $y=x$.  Presumably they mean $y \ne x$.

Comment: The first line $|x-y|\geq |x|+|y|$ is incorrect. The inequality goes the other way.

Comment: Thank you, Robert and Alex, I've fixed the above-mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's true for $x=0$, we may assume $x \ne 0$.  By symmetry, assume $x > 0$.
Let $x = a \cdot q^\beta$ with $a$ an integer, $q^{\ell-1} \le a \le q^{\ell} - 1$.
Let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be the greatest floating-point number $< x$ and the least floating-point number $>x$ respectively.
If $q^{\ell-1} < a$, then $y_1 = (a-1) \cdot q^\beta$ and 
$|x - y_1| = q^\beta$ while $x q^{-\ell} = a \cdot q^{\beta - \ell} < q^{\beta}$.
Similarly, if $a < q^{\ell}-1$, $|x - y_2| = q^\beta$.
I'll leave it to you to try $|x - y_1|$ with $a = q^{\ell-1}$ and $|x - y_2|$ with $a = q^{\ell}-1$.